# How to customize navigation menu in theme which is converted from pure html theme

Tags: menus

I am trying to convert a pure html theme to wordpress theme. I need to know how to make the navigation menus in the html theme (now it is on the way to converting to wordpress theme) for functioning properly. I registered the menu in functions.php

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
     )
   );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

What else i need to do, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Now where you want the menu in your theme, add something like this:

`if (has_nav_menu( 'header-menu' )) {
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) );
}`

Comment: Ok, thank you for your valuable time..also please let me know how to create navigation menu view or how to make the current navigation menu in html as 'header-menu'?

Comment: You don't do it in HTML.  Once you have all that in place, just go into wp-admin, create a menu, and assign it to the location "Header Menu"

Comment: Ok thank you..how can i get the exact styles for menus as in html theme? Currently menus are appearing but style are not applied..Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: Create a stylesheet, and enqueue it.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The css file having the styles for the menu is already en-queued. But how to specify the styles to be applied for that menu when the menu is called using the above php code? or is there any other method to add the class/id for the menu to be appeared?